# Как правильно разобрать JSON (библиотека org.json.simple.*)?

Tags: java, json

Здравствуйте.

Из файла загружается такого вида JSON

```
{  
  "from_excel":[  
    {  
      "solution":"Fisrt",
      "num":"1"
    },
    {  
      "solution":"Second",
      "num":"2"
    },
    {  
      "solution":"third",
      "num":"3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Пытаюсь на Java разобрать этот JSON таким образом, используя библиотеку **org.json.simple.***

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("E:\\json.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        out.println(jsonObject.get("from_excel"));

        JSONObject obj_new = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("from_excel");

        JSONArray solution = (JSONArray) obj_new.get("solution");

        Iterator iterator = solution.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

но где-то допускаю ошибку....

вот эта часть кода работает

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("E:\\json.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        out.println(jsonObject.get("from_excel"));
```

Как правильно разобрать этот JSON, используя эту библиотеку (использовать ее не догма, готов рассмотреть любые другие работающие варианты)?

Comment: Без указания того где и какую ошибку вы допустили помочь вам сложно

Comment: Буду рад если порекомендуете как поступить дальше после Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("E:\\json.txt"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        out.println(jsonObject.get("from_excel"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не по тому ключу массив получаете. Ваш массив находится по ключу from_excel

```
JSONArray solution = (JSONArray) obj_new.get("from_excel");

Iterator iterator = solution.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: На вот этой строке JSONObject obj_new = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("from_excel"); срабатывает ошибка - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: @NikolayBaranenko, всё верно. У вас, как я и написал, по ключу массив, а вы его кастуете к объекту. Посмотрите ещё раз какие я указал типы в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Работающий вариант

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj;
try {

    obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("E:\\json.txt"));

    out.println("<br>"+obj);

    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    JSONArray from_excel = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("from_excel");
    // вариант построчного вывода 1
    for(Object o: from_excel){
        out.println("<br>"+o);
    }
    // вариант построчного вывода 2
    Iterator iterator = from_excel.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        out.println("<br>"+iterator.next());
    }
    // вариант поименного вывода 3
    for (int i = 0; i < from_excel.size(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) from_excel.get(i);
        String num = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("num");
        String solution = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("solution");
        out.println("<br>num="+num+"; solution="+solution);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println("Ошибка: "+e);
}
```